# How to change Admob title color?

Tags: objective-c, admob

Does anyone know how to change the title color in banner view? I tried to use some additional parameters in SDK but can NOT change the title color (like WHITE) to another color (like RED):

```
GADAdMobExtras *extras = [[[GADAdMobExtras alloc] init] autorelease];
extras.additionalParameters =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   @"AAAAFF", @"color_bg",
   @"FFFFFF", @"color_bg_top",
   @"FFFFFF", @"color_border",
   @"000080", @"color_link",
   @"808080", @"color_text",
   @"008000", @"color_url",
   nil];
```

Please help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtAYy.png

Answer (score 1):

You can change it on Admob's website: http://apps.admob.com

Go:
Monetize (on the top of the site) -> All apps (on the left) -> Choose your app -> Click on link in "Ad unit" column -> under "Text ad style" select "Customized" -> Here you can define your desired colors for Title, Background, ...